Power BI How to set up data/measure to get averages at two different granularities in a Matrix visualization
This may be a duplicate question, but I am not sure of the correct wording to find the answer:
So the cleanest way I can think to ask this is: How do I get the average daily number of occurrences at a service level AND the average number of occurrences at a department level (There are multiple services in a department) in one matrix vis in Power BI?
I have a hierarchical dataset that I am trying to use to get the monthly averages. Departments are the higher level of Services. On the lower row (Service, I want it to display the Average daily occurrences, but on the Department level, it needs to be the sum of occurrences for all services that day, and then averaged.This is what it is doing currently:

It seems to be the answer: "The average on a service level." So instead of 10.02, it should be 18.13 on the Department Level. I verified this by building a 2nd table where I removed service, grouped by EVENT_DT and Department, and summed the Number of Occurrences.
How do I set up the data/matrix (do I need to create a measure?) to achieve this? The data currently is all in one table.
The dataset is straightforward, too. The granularity is EVENT_DT + Service:

The closest answer I have found is this link:
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Matrix-sum-at-lower-level-and-Average-at-Higher-level/td-p/1822545
But I just can't seem to figure out how to get it to average at a Department level; and it duplicates over months.

Average of two averages wouldn't be simply 'add them together and divide by two'. It needs to be calculated from the row level.

For daily average, try a Measure similar to:
Avg Daily Patients = 
  AVERAGEX(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[EVENT_DT]),
    CALCULATE( SUM('YourTable'[Number of Occurances]) )
  )

This should work for any level of your Matrix.

That kind of worked. It definitely got me other values in the, but I don't think it is rolling up on "average per day" for the Department level. It basically at two different granularities I want the data. On the "inner row (service)" I want the average Number of Occurances per EVENT_DT. Then, on the Department level, I want to sum the average number of occurrences to a department level per EVENT_DT, then average get the average again.

I'm a little lost. In your question I thought you wanted to add the averages below within a Department. Update your question and make it clear what average you want at the Service and what average you want at the department. If you are able to create a measure for each then I can help you create a third measure to display depending on what is in scope.

That's a very fair response, I am having trouble trying to get my ask across. Tell me if this makes it clearer-
Data is currently at an EVENT_DT + SERVICE level granularity (for example, on June 30, 2024, there were 13 patients in the service Burn). There is multiple SERVICE per department (ex., the Burn Service rolls up into BURN ICU). So to get the Department level patients per day, would have to add up all the services that roll up into it. What I would like is the "Average number of patients per service" that then on the dept. level, "Average number of patients per department"

Is it row per patient or is there a column for that? And you wanting avg per day for both service and dept?

It is one row per EVENT_DT and Service (so a count of patients for that day at that service)

the "Number of Occurrences" column is the count of patients that day

Try updated answer.

YES!!!! OMG THANK YOU! Jeeze, so little DAX to fix what I have been banging my head on all day!!! I REALLY REALLY appreciate the help!!!! THANK YOU
